# Django shell not able to execute ORM query

Tags: python, django

I am using Django shell for debug purpose of my project by using command `python manage.py shell`.

I have found that I am not able to execute ORM queries from shell & getting below kind of error.

```
from base.models import Template_Form, Template_Form_Field
Template_Form_Field.objects.all()
```

After executing above code in shell I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "base_template_form_field" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ions", "base_template_form_field"."sequence" FROM "base_temp...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\production\siralo\siralo_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "base_template_form_field" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ions", "base_template_form_field"."sequence" FROM "base_temp...
```

Does anybody have idea why am I getting above error & how to get rid of it.

I have tried to search on google but not able to find any solution.

Template form field model is as below.

```
class Template_Form_Field(models.Model):
    template_form = models.ForeignKey(Template_Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Caption')
    value_options = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Value options')
    sequence = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Sequence')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made and run all your migrations: `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`? Also, do you evaluate ORM queries at module level?

Comment: yes I have finished migrations & I am able to run same queries after runserver from py files but problem is not able to evaluate from shell. Is it possible to evaluate queries as I am doing it right now.

Comment: Can you please provide your Template_Form_Field  model ?

Comment: @MKPatel , I have added Template_Form_Field  model in question.

Answer (score 0):

just run **python manage.py migrate**
this error is  because you  have just run python manage.py makemigrations but did'nt run python manage.py migrate.

i also encounter the same error in shell while i have not run the migrate command below is the screen shot of error i get [this is the screenshot of the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYWJh.png)